# view new div based on option value of select tag using laravel

Tags: laravel

i have a dropdown list when i select any one option from list i should display an another form with name of the teacher  and subject of the teacher in textbox.The form is not displaying.when i select one item it should display the selected name and description box to add subjects of teachers that they interested please help me 
view page

---

```
<div class="portlet light bordered row">
    <h1>Add teacher subject</h1>
    <div class="row">

            <form action = "{{ url('subjectby/adding/process') }}" method = "POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class= "col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <h3>Choose Teachers </h3>
                                <div class="input-group"> 
                                        <div class="ui-widget border-dropdown" style="margin-left:50px;">

                                                    <select id="teacher" name="teachers" placeholder="Select Teacher">
                                                        <option value="">Select Teacher</option>
                                                        @foreach($user as $tec)
                                                            <option value="{{$tec->id}}">{{$tec->name}}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="new">
                       <div class="form-group">
                             <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="inputFacebook">Teacher Name</label>
                                <input type=hidden value="{{$tec->id}}" name="id">
                                <input type="text" value="{{$tec->name}}" class="form-control" name="name">
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label for="inputDescription">Subject Interested</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="intr" placeholder="Enter Subject Interest"> </textarea>
                            </div>

                        </div>

<div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                   <input type="submit" value="add" name=b1>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a `Laravel` specific problem.  You are taking about DOM manipulation and so you best bet is to use `jQuery` or `Vuejs` or even vanilla `Javascript` if you so choose.  Basically, you will write a script to watch for when your `<select>` changes, and then based on it's new value, show the part of the form you want.

Keep in mind that `Laravel` is a backend framework and so the user will never interact with it on a page.  After a page loads, `Laravel` has done all it can do until another request is made.  This is why `Javascript` was born - to let the user change things without reloading the page.